# Is it possible to have JAXB ignore order of elements in a <sequence> when one or more elements is a list (maxOccurs=unbounded)?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have been unable to find an answer to this. The `<all>` tag is not the answer, as it restricts child elements to `maxOccurs=“1”`.

Say you had XSD that included:

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name=“name” type=“xsd:string” minOccurs=“1”/>
  <xsd:element name=“children” type=“xsd:string” minOccurs=“0” maxOccurs=“unbounded”/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Is there any way to get JAXB to use this XSD to read XML where the ordering of elements is not the same as defined in the XSD?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a full solution with JAXB.

However, the JAXB binding for

`<xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="children" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>`

will unmarshall the instances that you want and keeps them stable when marshalling them again.

Downsides are:

- The corresponding Java class has a (typed) List childrenOrName, not two individual properties (in which case you would loose the position of your name element anyway)
- You have to check manually that there is exactly one name in your list.

Comment: When you say the list is typed, I assume you mean as a String? What would happen if I used a complex type (defined somewhere in the XSD file) instead of a string as one of the elements? Would it then be List<?>?

Comment: In the above example, you would get List<JAXBElement<String>>, because xjc would generate @XmlElementRefs. This happens because the the type (xs:string) alone is not enough to distinguish the two possible elements here - you also need the element name. The same would happen, if you used a complex type "T1" for both "children" and "name" (gives you List<JAXBElement<T1>>). If you used two different and unrelated complex type "T1" and "T2", you would get List<Object> with direct instances of T1 and T2 as list elements (no intermediate JAXBElement) - so you could use "instance of" to distinguish.

Comment: (If you had a common supertype T for both T1 and T2, it would be List<T>.)